# Can $A + uv^T$ be non-singular if A(order n) has rank n-1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, schur-complement

Suppose $A$ is a matrix of order $n$ with rank n-1, $u$ and $v$ are $n$-vectors. Can $A + uv^T$ be nonsingular, if yes then find such $u$ and $v$.

First I wrote Rank$(A + uv^T) <=$ Rank$(A)$ + Rank$(uv^T)$

Then  I wrote $n-1 <=$ Rank$(A + uv^T) <= n$ (which I am not sure of)

Then tried to take $v$ in the kernel of $A$ but to no avail. How to approach?

Comment: I'm confused on the quantifiers here. Do you mean "Are there $A, u, v$ such that ...?", or is it "Given an arbitrary rank $n-1$ matrix $A$, are there always $u, v$ such that ...?"

Comment: A is fixed. So, hopefully u and v in some terms of A=$(a_(ij))$

Comment: @Arthur the latter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trivially, yes: take u=(1,0,0..,0)(column vector), v=(1,0,0...,0) and A to be the matrix that has 1 everywhere on the diagonal except at (1,1) (and 0 everywhere else). Then $A + uv^T= I$.

Adding in my comment, for the (not so trivial)case of an arbitrary fixed matrix A of rank (n-1):

$A$ is of rank (n-1) => there are invertible matrices(corresponding to elementary transforms) X,Y such that $A=XI_{n−1}Y$ where by $I_{n−1}$ I denoted the matrix with 1 on the main diagonal everywhere except at position (1,1). But now choose $u=Xu, v=Y^Tv$, where u,v are the columns I defined above in my answer and then you get that $A+uv^T=X(I_{n−1}+uv^T)Y=XY $ is invertible

Comment: yes, nice example. But what if A is fixed. Like A=$a_(ij)$

Comment: @AvinashBhawnani Then bring it to Jordan normal form by a similarity transformation.

Comment: We haven't studied that yet. Is there a more basic way?

Comment: I have updated my answer to cover this case too @AvinashBhawnani

Comment: v should be $Y^Tv$, right?

Comment: Ok, sure, I updated

Answer (score -1):

If either u or v are in the row space or column space of A respectively then A + uv’ will remain singular.  So if A = ab’  with a and b vectors (A is rank one) and say v=const * b then A + uv’ will remain a rank one matrix.